# Tell me how to fix the Playback error on the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video

I tried to play video using .m3u8.
However, when the video that was running on IOS runs on Android, an error appears
The error code looks like this.

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 400
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:413)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:263)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.prepareExtraction(HlsMediaChunk.java:495)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.feedDataToExtractor(HlsMediaChunk.java:468)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.loadMedia(HlsMediaChunk.java:437)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsMediaChunk.load(HlsMediaChunk.java:394)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 4205):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

And this is my Android code.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <application
            android:label="flutter_example"
            android:name="${applicationName}"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

I've added everything from the document to add when using the lecle_yoyo_layer package. Please tell me how

I've tried many ways, but I can't find one, so I'm writing.